# Работа с FTP через PROXY

Tags: python

Добрый день!

Подскажите, как установить соединение с FTP сервером через Proxy сервер? Без прокси соединяюсь через ftplib, и все прекрасно работает. Может быть для работы через прокси использовать pycurl или какой-то другой модуль?

Спасибо!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ftplib import FTP

#----Load file from FTP server----------------  
def GetFile(ftp,files):  
    folder = '/home/ivb/Bases/'  
    for f in files:  
        print '********************'  
        print 'Download the file: %s' % f  
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + f, open(folder + f,'wb').write)  
    ftp.quit()

ftp = FTP('92.126.x.x')  
ftp.login('USER','PASS')  
ftp.cwd('/Share/Base')  
files = ['ASDNR.backup','ahov.backup','Doc.backup','si.backup',  
     'gar.backup','Navsys.backup','Tablchs.backup','Report_MCHS.backup']  
GetFile(ftp,files)
```

Comment: Ну наверное использовать что-то другое, например urllib2

Comment: @Ivan Babintsev, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой, решил ее используя вот это:
https://code.google.com/p/socksipy-branch/ , и чуть позже нашел (но не проверил) https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks

P.S. простите за некропостинг :)